# Space for ad appearing blank on the right column - second time

Tags: discussion, bug, advertising

I had filed a bug-report on [this (now deleted) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321216/blank-ad-space-looking-weird). It was closed as not reproducible. As per the close text, if we encounter the same problem again, we should post a new question. So here I am.

---

The space on the right is normally filled with an ad, and looks like this:

[image]

I noticed yesterday that this was empty:

[image]

[image]

This looks like a bug to me.

This is confirmed a bug, as I've seen this the second time. I reported [this back also.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321216/blank-ad-space-looking-weird).

I asked in chat if someone is able to reproduce this, but I got a no. Even this appeared to me only the second time. This looks quite rare, but is a bug.

Could the SO team look into this matter?

I don't use an adblocker. The js console wasn't showing any errors. I have few extensions, but all are well known ones:

- "View Vote totals" without 1000 rep (version 1.5.7) (this is from SE)
- Google Docs (version 0.9)
- Google Sheets (version 1.1)
- Google Slides (version 0.9)

I don't use any user scripts. I use Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit). I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

For <10k users, to see the deleted post, view the images in order.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acm6u.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J61vT.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdI6.png)

Comment: I suspect this may be related to a request just timing out. Some days we see issues with some ads taking longer than they should to load. If your connection is sub-optimal, that may compound the effects.

Comment: @stevvve My connection is optimal. On somedays it's slow, but on the day I experienced this, it wasn't slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to repro yet. However, those ads are actually served by Adzerk, not StackOverflow. In a few cases an Adzerk campaign will attempt to load an ad creative that we serve, but most are static assets also served by Adzerk.

I'd be happy to take a look, but it would be helpful if the next time this happens you could post a screenshot of the expanded DOM element in Chrome's Dev Tools? That would help me pin down which campaign is potentially causing the issue, and whether it's an ad served by us or Adzerk.

Comment: Okay. But first I have to see how to expand DOM element in Dev tools. I'll check that out and do it. If I repro it again.